# What's the equivalent approach in Umbraco 7 to "Insert content area placeholder" button

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6

I am learning Umbraco.
The installed version on my machine is 7.1.3(if I am correct, at least I am sure it's V7), but the free video tutorials uses V6(WebForm) or earlier version.

I saw the guy clicked a button "Insert content area placeholder" on a template page, but I cannot find it on the V7 template page.

Does anyone know how to do this in V7(MVC)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using webforms:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="YOURNAMEGOESHERE" runat="server" />
```

Using MVC:

```
@section YOURNAMEGOESHERE {
    <!-- YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE -->
}
```

Comment: so there is no UI interface to enable users to Insert content area placeholder in Version 7? We have to do it manually ?

Comment: Indeed - unfortunately.